# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'classList' of null' javascript error in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm having some problems converting javascript from a static site into a rails app.

The javascript was originally in a main.js file, located in the same folder (app/assets/javascripts/channels) as application.js

When the bug occurred, I copied and pasted all of the javascript into application.js, and the bug has persisted.

The issue is that the "Tabs component" is not functioning as expected.

Here is the code for application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

console.log('apps')

$(function () {
  const doc = document.documentElement

  doc.classList.remove('no-js')
  doc.classList.add('js')

  // Reveal animations
  if (document.body.classList.contains('has-animations')) {
    /* global ScrollReveal */
    const sr = window.sr = ScrollReveal()

    sr.reveal('.hero-title, .hero-paragraph, .hero-cta', {
      delay: 150,
      duration: 1000,
      distance: '60px',
      easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)',
      origin: 'bottom',
      interval: 150
    })

    sr.reveal('.hero-right-decoration', {
      duration: 1000,
      distance: '40px',
      easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)',
      origin: 'top'
    })

    sr.reveal('.hero-left-decoration', {
      duration: 1000,
      distance: '40px',
      easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)',
      origin: 'bottom'
    })

    sr.reveal('.clients li', {
      delay: 300,
      duration: 1000,
      rotate: {
        y: 50
      },
      easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)',
      interval: 150
    })

    sr.reveal('.feature, .tabs-links li, .testimonial, .pricing-table, .pricing-faqs, .cta-inner', {
      duration: 600,
      distance: '40px',
      easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)',
      interval: 100,
      origin: 'bottom',
      viewFactor: 0.2
    })
  }

  // Accordion component
  const accordionEl = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-title')

  if (accordionEl.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < accordionEl.length; i++) {
      accordionEl[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.parentNode.classList.toggle('is-open')
        const panel = this.nextElementSibling
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = `${panel.scrollHeight}px`
        }
      })
    }
  }

  // Tabs component
  const tabLinksAll = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-link')

  if (tabLinksAll.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < tabLinksAll.length; i++) {
      tabLinksAll[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let tabLinksContainer = tabLinksAll[i].parentNode.parentNode
        let tabPanels = tabLinksContainer.nextElementSibling.getElementsByClassName('tab-panel')
        let tabLinks = tabLinksContainer.getElementsByClassName('tab-link')
        // Remove is-active class from all links and panels
        for (let i = 0; i < tabLinks.length; i++) {
          tabLinks[i].classList.remove('is-active')
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < tabPanels.length; i++) {
          tabPanels[i].classList.remove('is-active')
        }
        // Get the ID of panel to display
        let tabID = this.getAttribute('href')
        // Add is-active class to matching link and panel
        tabLinksAll[i].classList.add('is-active')
        document.querySelector(tabID).classList.add('is-active')
      })
    }
  }
}())
```

And here is the code for application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Time to Solve</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i|PT+Serif:700" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
<body class="is-boxed has-animations">
  <div class="body-wrap boxed-container">
    <%= render 'header' %>
    <main>
      <%= yield %>
    </main>
    <%= render 'footer' %>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.__lo_site_id = 131080;

      (function() {
        var wa = document.createElement('script'); wa.type = 'text/javascript'; wa.async = true;
        wa.src = 'https://d10lpsik1i8c69.cloudfront.net/w.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(wa, s);
        })();
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a video showing the expected functionality (javascript working on static site) compared to the bug in the rails app:

https://gfycat.com/dopeyseveralarawana

You can also see the difference live.

Working version (static site): https://www.timetosolve.com/
Broken version (rails app): http://157.230.113.47

When the live rails app loads, it produces this Javascript Console:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
>       at application-caea9b4f287ad158d308b89377798bc0c94901b3964f77d10250a2f29eadd1d6.js:481*

The console also produces these messages when clicking on one of the tab components:

> *[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took ms     1619:04:56.916 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a
>   scroll-blocking  event. Consider marking event handler as
>   'passive' to make the page more responsive. See 
>
>   819:05:05.362 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took ms*

Not very experienced here (this javascript code is directly from a static html/css/js template), so any help and guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to tell where this is coming from, but if I had to bet, based on my experience with errors like this, the js, since it is getting loaded in the head, is looking for an element it can't find because it has not loaded yet.  A quick test would be to move the js include to the bottom, right above the end body tag, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RockwellRice

I added a defer attribute to the javascript include tag, and the page is now loading without errors.

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', :defer => "defer", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

However, the problem persists.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Your site `https://www.timetosolve.com/` is not loading, when I go to this link `http://157.230.113.47` it looks to me like that tabs are working just fine.  You are getting an error that `main.js` can't be found so I would fix that, but the tabs are working fine for me in chrome, safari, firefox, and opera.